# Override mute switch with SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

when the external mute switch is on the app has no sound. I use SimpleAudioEngine in my app to play sound effects.
How can I play sounds even if the mute switch is set to silent?

Comment: It doesn't work this way. If a user mutes the device, you can't override it-- all apps get muted.

Comment: is there any way to get working.I see in other app it working.

Comment: The mute button mutes. Nuff said. Apple might not approve respectively might remove your app from the App Store if they find out or hear your app doesn't play by the rules.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent your user from being able to mute the sound?? Trying to irritate them?

Answer (score 1):

If you initialise with `[CDAudioManager initAsynchronously:kAMM_PlayAndRecord];` the mute switch is overridden. This is as far as I know also the only way to get microphone input.

Comment: This answer will allow you to play audio even if the mute switch is engaged, but why actively annoy your users? If they've got the mute switch on, it very likely means that they don't want to hear anything from your (or any other) app.

Answer (score 0):

When I used `[CDAudioManager initAsynchronously:kAMM_PlayAndRecord];` I was faced with a very low volume problem. Use `[CDAudioManager initAsynchronously:kAMM_MediaPlayback];` instead and volume won't be affected.

This will also work in [cocos2d-x](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) (either with c++ or js) since that also uses [cc.audioengine](/questions/tagged/cc.audioengine).